# Why object's value changes even though it has different references?

Tags: c#, oop, reference

I am confused about objects references here. It is LC problem to merge 2 sorted linked lists.

I understand that at first iteration `current.next` and `result` have reference the same object so when i assign new value to `current.next` the `result` value changes as well.

At the second iteration both r1 and r2 are false so `result, current and current.next` point to diffrent objects.

What i don't understand is why assigning new value to current (`current = current.next`) doesn't modify result object but `current.next = l1/l2` does?

Could someone explain it to me please?

```
public static ListNode MergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2)
        {
            if (l1 == null) return l2;
            if (l2 == null) return l1;
            if (l2 == null && l1 == null) return null;

            ListNode result = new ListNode(0);
            ListNode current = result;

            while (l1 != null && l2 != null)
            {
                var r1 = Object.ReferenceEquals(result, current);
                var r2 = Object.ReferenceEquals(result, current.next);
                
                if (l1.val < l2.val)
                {
                    current.next = l1;
                    l1 = l1.next;
                }
                else
                {
                    current.next = l2;
                    l2 = l2.next;
                }

                current = current.next;
            }

            // l1 is lognger than l2 
            if(l1 != null)
            {
                current.next = l1;
                l1 = l1.next;
            }

            // l2 is lognger than l1 
            if (l2 != null)
            {
                current.next = l2;
                l2 = l2.next;
            }

            return result.next;
        }
```

```
public class ListNode
    {
        public int val;
        public ListNode next;
        public ListNode(int x = 0, ListNode next = null)
        {
            val = x;
            next = null;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Let's say we have these:

```
Input: l1 = [1,2,4], l2 = [1,3,4]    Output: [1,1,2,3,4,4]
```

**1st iteration :**

`r1 = true`, both result and current point to the same object.

`r2 = false`

`l1.val == l2.val` so we execute

```
else
{
  current.next = l2;
  l2 = l2.next;
}
```

At this moment we have:
`result = [0,1,3,4]`, `current = [0,1,3,4], l2 = [3,4]`

Next we execute `current = current.next`, so `current = [1,3,4]` and it doesn't point to result anymore.

**2nd iteration**

`r1 = false`, both result and current point to the different object.

`r2 = false`,

`l1.val < l2.val` so we execute

```
if (l1.val < l2.val)
{
    current.next = l1;
    l1 = l1.next;
}
```

At this moment we have:

```
result = [0,1,1,2,4], current = [1,1,2,4], l2 = [3,4], l1 = [2,4]
```

Here is the part i don't understand : Result and current point to diffrent objects, still when current changes result does as well. How result keeps reference to current??

Next we execute `current = current.next`, so `current = [1,2,4]`, so we modify current but this time result doesn't change.

Comment: you don't assign new value with `current = current.next`. You assign new *reference* to variable `current`. So it does not point to object referenced by `result` anymore.

Comment: @YegorAndrosov yes thanks i got that part they point to diffrent objects but still keep some reference as they keep changing. I provided some explanation.

Comment: @kenarf, result contains reference to 0 node (from constructor), and then in first operation you assign l1 or l2 to result.next object and finally assign current to current.next, so result.next becomes current. while loop repeats every node is appended to the end of result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Result and current point to diffrent objects, still when current changes result does as well. How result keeps reference to current?

Look at this part of your question:

> so `current = [1,3,4]` and it doesn't point to result anymore.

Importantly, the `1` in that list *is the same element* as the `1` in `result = [0,1,3,4]`. If you modify the `next` field of that `1` node, you will modify any list that node is a member of. Including the list that `result` is referencing.

Later when you write:

> At this moment we have:
>
> `result = [0,1,1,2,4], current = [1,1,2,4], l2 = [3,4], l1 = [2,4]`

Note that the list `result` points to is *not* the same as the list `current` points to. But after that first node, it *is* the same.

After the first iteration, `result.next` references the same object that `current` does. This is because `result` and `current` started at referencing the same object, and then as the last step of the first iteration, `current` was changed to reference `current.next`. Since `current` and `result` were at that point the same, `current.next` and `result.next` are also the same. So after changing `current` to `current.next`, that's the same as setting it to `result.next`.

So on the second iteration, `result.next` and `current` are the same. This means that when you modify `current.next`, that's the same as modifying `result.next.next`, which has the effect of replacing the contents of the `result` list beyond the first two elements, with the new chain of elements that `l2` referenced.

Again: the key here is that each variable simply points to a single node. It's fine to conceptualize that as pointing to a list of nodes, but only if you remember that if you modify the `next` field of any node in that list, you are modifying the entire list, even if the variable is not referencing the variable that references the root of the list.

Answer (score -1):

You should never assign `current.next` to nodes from `l1` or `l2`.  Instead you must create a new `ListNode` that has the same value as `l1` or `l2` and make `current.next` point to your new `ListNode`.  Otherwise you're trying to straighten a bowl of spaghetti, which is an impossible task. You need to build your own new strand of spaghetti.

Comment: The question isn't saying the code doesn't work, just that they don't understand it.  It's *not* impossible to take two linked lists and mutate them into a single merged linked list.  You may think making a new linked list with all new nodes is preferable (which, frankly, is hard to justify in the absence of any context whatsoever), but that doesn't mean mutating the existing one is *impossible* as you claim.

Comment: @Servy, ok, I never considered that approach.  It would definitely be more space-efficient.